# How to extract opencv Mat header?

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I want to send OpenCV Mat images to a ftp server and the input to my ftp function is `uchar *`

I have access to data part of Opencv images by using **.data** method but I don't know how to acess to header information to put is infront of .data and send the whole as a complete image. So I need to extract the header information of OpenCV Mat structure.

I also need to add some information to the header about the image and change the whole **header + data** to **uchar *** so that I can send it through. I need something like this:

```
cv::Mat Myimage(100,100,CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar::all(0));
uchar * Myimagedata = Myimage.data;
uchar * Myimageheader = Header_Extractor(Myimage);
uchar * Complete_Image = Myimageheader + Myimagedata;
SEND_FTP(Complete_Image);
```

Comment: It would be much easier to use your own simple protocol for this - send a struct containing the number of rows, columns, and opencv data type, then send the raw bytes. It will be easier to reconstruct a `Mat` from this at the receiving end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not send a png or jpg [encoded image](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode) ? you should prefer this to your current approach for a couple of reasons:

- it comes with a builtin protocol already
- please, never send uncompressed pixels over a network
- what would your poor ftp server do with a cv::Mat ?

---

```
vector<uchar> buffer;
imencode(".png", MyImage, buffer);
SEND_FTP(&(buffer[0]));
```

hmm, wait, that would need a send function, where you can pass the length, too. your SEND_FTP func probably tries strlen, which won't work on binary data. (same problem with your original idea, btw)

also, you will have to switch the ftp connection to binary mode.

---

i highly doubt, that you *really* want a cv::Mat serialized to an ftp server (how would that get saved on the other side, even?), but *if* you want to send one, you might be better off, not sending the complete Mat header(it's a complex beast), but something more simple, like rows,cols,type, data (and make sure, your Mat isContinous()).

Comment: Perfect answer, I've used this imencode function in another project but I've forget to use it in this one. Thanks a lot berak :)